# Check scheduled tasks Spring

Tags: xml, spring, scheduled-tasks

There is a need to check the scheduled tasks in the xml file:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
  <task:scheduled ref="task" method="execute"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

But they can be commented out:

```
<--<task:scheduled-tasks>
  <task:scheduled ref="task" method="execute"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>-->
```

I'm trying to do this in a controller:

```
@Autowired
ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar;

... // some code

public List<Task> getScheduledTasks() {
  List<Task> allTasks = new ArrayList<>();
  allTasks.addAll(scheduledTaskRegistrar.getFixedDelayTaskList());
  allTasks.addAll(scheduledTaskRegistrar.getFixedRateTaskList());
  allTasks.addAll(scheduledTaskRegistrar.getCronTaskList());
  allTasks.addAll(scheduledTaskRegistrar.getTriggerTaskList());
  return allTasks;
}
```

And if the tasks are commented out on the xml file, then I get the following error:

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.config.ContextLifecycleScheduledTaskRegistrar] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

Comment: Try to use `@Autowired(required=false)` instead of `@Autowired` and test if `scheduledTaskRegistrar` is null (ie, commented out) before calling `get...` methods. Is it what you're looking for ?

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work @Autowired(required=false) (

Comment: Just make sure that `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` class is declared with a `@Component` annotation or created as a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class, just be aware of something , try to use other package name different to the spring framework package structure in order to recognize in a simple way where the error comes from.